# Pandas Dataframe: Select row where column contains X, in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

So I am struggling with this data processing, I have a data file with 
~100 rows * 24 columns.

I load the file with

```
data = pd.read_csv(fileName, header=[0,1])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Then I only want to work on a part of it so I select only those columns:

```
postSurvey = questionaireData[['QUESTNNR','PS01_01', 'PS02_01', 'PS02_02', 'PS03_01', 'PS03_02', 'PS03_03', 'PS04', 'PS05', 'PS06', 'PS07_01']]
```

**Problem:** Now I want to select the rows which contain 'PS' in 'QUESTNNR' 
I can create this "list" of True/false, but when I try to use it i get:

```
onlyPS = postSurvey['QUESTNNR'] == 'PS'
postSurvey = postSurvey[onlyPS]
ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names
```

With this I get:

```
postSurvey.xs('PS', level='QUESTNNR')
AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'get_loc_level'
```

I have tried all sorts of solutions from stackoverflow and other sources, but need help.

dataframe:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       Q       W       E       R       T       Y       U       I       O       P       S       J       K       L       Z       X       C       V       N       M       A1      A2      A3      S4      F4      G5
ASDF1   ASDF2   ASDF3   ASDF4   ASDF5   ASDF6   ASDF7   ASDF8   ASDF9   ASDF10  ASDF11  ASDF12  ASDF13  ASDF14  ASDF15  ASDF16  ASDF17  ASDF18  ASDF19  ASDF20  ASDF21  ASDF22  ASDF23  ASDF24  ASDF25  ASDF26  ASDF27  ASDF28  ASDF29  ASDF30  ASDF31  ASDF32  ASDF33  ASDF34
138     PS  interview   eng     date                                                        10  2   5   7   2012    10  1   13  1   26  1   0   1   1
129     QB2 interview   eng     date    4   6   5       56,10,34,7,20                                                                           1   0   2   2
130     QC1 interview   eng     date    6   2   6           7                                                                       1   0   2   2
131     QD2 interview   eng     date    3   8   6               5,8,15                                                                  1   0   2   2
```

Comment: `postSurvey[postSurvey['QUESTNNR'].eq('PS')]` tell me the output of this one.

Comment: output: 
ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names

Comment: @Rickeyhb can you try `postSurvey[postSurvey['QUESTNNR'].eq('PS').values]` I havent faced this error till today. Might be because of multi index presence.

Comment: @Dark I also need one where it is not equal to PS, to get all others?

Comment: There is an inversion operation called tilde (`~`)  to convert True to False, So use `postSurvey[~postSurvey['QUESTNNR'].eq('PS').values]`

Comment: Now I need a clever way to get postSurvey['QUESTNNR'].eq('QA1').values and postSurvey['QUESTNNR'].eq('QA2').values, into one Dataframe ?

Comment: solved it using np.logical_or